# 'Out of memory exception' when processing 67000 records in reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, devexpress

I have an extra report with **"62976"** records with 71 columns. I have tried to load this report in a reportviewer control and I got "Out of Memory Exception" after several minutes. Is there any way to load this report in report viewer? I am using xtraReports of devexpress.

My code consists of a dataset that is filled with this 62976 records. I do some record manipulations using foreach for this many records and finally the output from this foreach is fed to the reportviewer. I have tried debugging and the debugger passes all the code lines without failure. Finally I see the reportviewer with the loading image running (which implies that large amount of data is being processed) and after around 60 seconds, the exception is thrown.

**Things I've tried.**

Clearing the temp folder
Restarting visual studio
Restarting my machine

Comment: There might me such situation while getting so many records. Can you get top 1000 records or so? I thing you should Try it out first

Comment: Increase the size of your swap. Or buy more RAM. Or talk to the DevExpress people. Or try to process the data in smaller chunks.

Comment: Does your dataset contain any images?

Comment: No. Just plain records.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the Devexpress report controls  seems to have lot of memory leak issues.We had an issue with the XtaRichEditControl  and has to totally remove it from the project.However 67000 is huge number depending on your system configuration.The reports do consumes lot of resources.

You can try using a memory profiler to find out which class/object is using most memory.We used [Ans memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

The other option is to use WinDbg  with SOS .